# How to mount window share in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have window server which shares the folder called wwwroot.

In my ubuntu that window computer is not visible.

When i press `ctrl + L`

and type `smb://window-comp-name/wwwroot`

Then it works

I tried mounting that folder using

```
sudo mount smb://SERVER/wwwroot /media/dir1
```

but it didn't work

I tried this and it worked. Can anyone explain me why my initial method don't work

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.101/wwwroot /media/sputold_server -o username=administrator,password=877780,iocharset=utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gvfs-mount` instead. The remote volume will be mounted under `~/.gvfs`.

The reason you can't mount using URLs is because `mount` doesn't recognize URLs.

Comment: I tried that and it say "Error mounting location: volume doesn't implement mount"

Comment: I used this command "sudo gvfs-mount smb://SERVER/wwwroot /media/sputold_server
"

Comment: Changed my post

Comment: That would be because `gvfs-mount` isn't used for mounting parts of the local filesystem. Remove both the sudo and the "/media/...".

Comment: Try executing `export $(dbus-launch) before you use `gvfs-mount`. See this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44318/30132).

Answer (score 0):

Did you install smbfs ?

```
aptitude install smbfs
```

Your cifs command looks fine. If you need more informations :

http://www.deimos.fr/blocnotesinfo/index.php?title=AutoFS_:_montage_et_d%C3%A9montage_de_partages